# Paste contents of range into 3 different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to copy the contents of my starting sheet in Range("B1:D7") to the files listed in Range("A1:A3") using a For Each Loop. It runs perfect until it tries to open the second file and gives a error 1004. This is my first time using VBA so I am up for any suggestions. Thanks

```
Sub testingLoops()
Dim theRange As Range
Set copyFrom = Workbooks.Open("start.xlsm")
      For Each theRange In Range("A1:A3")
      copyFrom.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:D7").Copy
      Set pasteTo = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\" + theRange.Value + ".xlsx")
      pasteTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:D7").PasteSpecial
      pasteTo.Close
    Next theRange
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

This is my code after the first answer still getting the same result

```
Option Explicit

Sub testingLoops()

Dim theRange As Range
Dim copyFrom As Workbook
Dim pasteTo As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each theRange In Range("A1:A3")

Set copyFrom = ThisWorkbook

copyFrom.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:D7").Copy

Set pasteTo = Workbooks.Open("C:\myFolder\" + theRange + ".xlsx")

pasteTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:D7").PasteSpecial

pasteTo.Close

Next theRange

copyFrom.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You must have invalid filename in A2.

Comment: so my a1 = "x20" my a2 = "x30" and my a3 = "x40". No matter what order I put them in, the second file is always 'invalid'... For example in the current order x20 opens and is copied to fine but x30 is not. then when I put x30 first, x30 opens and is copied to fine but x20 is not

Comment: 1004 is an application or object definition error. Add Option Explicit to your code module, and declare the Workbook variables (copyFrom and pasteTo). The code is generally ok ... so there is something else contributing to the 1004 error, so declaring variables etc should help you get to the next step.

Comment: How are you dealing with the alert when you close each workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Further to the above comment ... this code based on yours works (I've changed the directory location). It might help you debug yours ...

**start.xlsm**

[image: start.xlsm]

And the code which presumably you're running from a different workbook/code module ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub testingLoops()

    Dim theRange As Range
    Dim copyFrom As Workbook
    Dim pasteto As Workbook

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set copyFrom = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\start.xlsm")
    For Each theRange In Range("A1:A3")
        copyFrom.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:D7").Copy
        Set pasteto = Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\" + theRange.Value + ".xlsx")
        pasteto.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:D7").PasteSpecial
        pasteto.Close
    Next theRange
    copyFrom.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

and in c:\temp

[image: screen]

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion. Might want to swap out the `+`'s for true `&` string concatenation operators and give a parent worksheet to Range("A1:A3"). `pasteto.Close savechanges:=true` would be nice.

Comment: This still did not work for me unfortunately. I did update to use an entire file extension and have all the files in the same folder but still getting the 1004 error the second time through. @Jeeped I do plan on adding the close and save once I know that the copy is working for all files. I just like to have them open to check. Also I am running this from the start.xlsm file not sure if this would hurt loading the second file to pasteTo but thought I would mention

Comment: @Joe, (1) if you are running this from start.xlsm then why does your code try to open start.xlsm? (2) I built a sandbox test bed with multiple workbooks and what, for all intents and purposes was near identical code to the above. It ran through without problems.

Comment: This is my first time with VBA so I'm kind of learning as I go. Is there anything on my computer that could mess with finding the file? I have them all in the same folder now and using the entire directory address. I have also changed it to just use ThisWorkbook and not try to open start.xlsm anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So after some toying around I finally found a method that works. It seems that concatenating the file extension was my problem. Why? I am not sure but putting the .xlsx file extension in my range A1:A3 ended up working and saving to all 3 files!

```
Option Explicit

Sub testingLoops()

Dim theRange As Range
Dim pasteTo As Workbook

For Each theRange In Range("A1:A3")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:D7").Copy

Set pasteTo = Workbooks.Open("C:\myFolder\" & theRange)

pasteTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:D7").PasteSpecial

pasteTo.Save

pasteTo.Close

Next theRange

End Sub
```